# FloatingTips with stay active on hover

Tags: mootools, tooltip

I am using FloatingTip tool tip for my project and i am struggling for how to stay active and not to be closed when cursor is on tooltip. 
Hear is jsFiddle `[`http://jsfiddle.net/SLvUz/3/`][1]`
For example: When mouse hover to tooltip and anchor **Let me see!** tooltip stay open.

Detail link: https://github.com/lorenzos/FloatingTips

Any ideas or suggestions? Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately this plugin doesn't have such option at the moment, but it has methods and events, so you can implement this behavior using them. The code may look like following:

```
$$('#advanced a').each(function(elem){
    var instance = new FloatingTips(elem, {
        // example options
        content: function() { return $('htmlcontent'); },
        html: true,         // I want that content is interpreted as HTML
        center: false,      // I do not want to center the tooltip
        arrowOffset: 16,    // Arrow is a little more the the right
        offset: { x: -10 }, // Position offset {x, y}

        // override show/hide events
        showOn: null,
        hideOn: null
    });

    // customize tooltip behavior
    var delay = 100, timer;

    var tipHover = function() {
        clearTimeout(timer);
    }
    var tipLeave = function() {
        clearTimeout(timer);
        timer = setTimeout(function(){
            instance.hide(elem);    
        }, delay);
    }

    instance.addEvents({
        show: function(tip, elem){
            tip.addEvents({
                mouseover: tipHover,
                mouseout: tipLeave                    
            });
        },
        hide: function(tip, elem){
            tip.removeEvents({
                mouseover: tipHover,
                mouseout: tipLeave                    
            });   
        }
    });

    elem.addEvents({
        mouseover: function() {
            clearTimeout(timer);
            timer = setTimeout(function(){
                instance.show(elem);    
            }, delay);                
        },
        mouseout: function() {
            clearTimeout(timer);
            timer = setTimeout(function(){
                instance.hide(elem);    
            }, delay);  
        }
    });
});
```

Check updated fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/SLvUz/455/